# Rails 3 - vote_fu - link_to vote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins

I'm using the vote_fu plugin to take care of some super simple voting. What I have is a link as my voteable, and a user as my voter.

I have successfully been able to vote for a link in my console.

What I'm struggling with is rendering this in a view.

In my link controller, I have the following method:

```
def vote
@link = link.find(params[:id])
current_user.vote_up(@link)
redirect_to :back
end
```

My view, which I have played around with, looks as following:

```
  <% @links.each do |link| %>
  <div class="scoreboard">
    <%= link_to link.votes_for, :url => vote_link_path(link) %>
  </div>
```

The error when trying the render the view is:

```
undefined method `link_votes_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000004b29568>:0x00000004b1a6a8>
```

So it is the path (I feel) that I've been tinkering with to no success. I thought maybe it was my routes, but I'm unsure what do add for vote_fu. Here's my routes.rb content:

```
  resources :links
  resource :users
  resource :session, :controller => "sessions"
  match '/login' => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
  match '/logout' => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
```

Anyway, I was wondering if anyone has successfully implemented a simple voting solution via vote_fu that could point me towards what I'm doing wrong. I know the plugin is working due to the console being fine, but my controller/view/routes must be messed up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a route for your method — something like this:

```
resources :links do
  member do
    post 'vote'
  end
end
```

Then you can use

```
link_to "Vote", vote_link_path(link), :method => :post
```